# In a document library, is there a way to include document views (visible in the information pane) as a column?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, metadata, web-analytics, modern-document-library

In SharePoint document libraries, in Modern view, you can select a file and see, in the information pane, how many times it has been viewed. This is fine if you're only tracking a few documents. But it would be great if it could be included as a column in the list view, along with other document metadata. Is there a way to make that happen--either in Modern or Classic view?

Answer (score 1):

Per my knowledge, there is no similar feature to page viewed times in list view. You can post this idea in [UserVoice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/) for MS team to take a look at.

For what we have now in SharePoint Online, we can check the [site usage](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/view-usage-data-for-your-sharepoint-site-2fa8ddc2-c4b3-4268-8d26-a772dc55779e?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). You can have a quite clear view with more decent data about the usage of contents in your site.